# Node - How to use a variable inside a path.join?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a require path join where the name of the ending file is a variable.

```
module.exports = function render(locals) {

  const language = locals.path.split('/')[1]
  return Promise.resolve(
    locals.ejsCompile(
      //require(`../i18n-build/index.${language}.js`)
      require(path.join(__dirname, "i18n-build", "index", ${language}.js))
    )
  )
};
```

I'm getting this error , I think because the part `${language}.js` is not included properly insid ethe path.join

```
error  Module parse failed: Unexpected token You may need an appropriate
9:35:49 AM:                loader to handle this file type. |     locals.ejsCompile( |
9:35:49 AM:                //require(`../i18n-build/index.${language}.js`) >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a template string you need back-quotes. According to your commented code you probably want

```
require(path.join(__dirname, "i18n-build", `index.${language}.js`))
```

The same with string concatenation would be

```
require(path.join(__dirname, "i18n-build", "index."+language+".js"))
```

Comment: thank for your help ! It worked.  i had tried the concat method but with ${language} so it failed. Understand now why.